# Is double colon access (::) to class member thread safe?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

There are two types of call to the member of a class, one is directly refer to the member function of a particular object using dot (`.`), the other method is to use double colon e.g. `Obj::function()`.

My question is, is the double colon call to member is a thread-safe operation?

Comment: I don't think that `::` says _anything_ in general about thread-safety. Probably you have to ask the author of the library you plan to use and/or read the documentation of that library.

Comment: The double-colon `::` is the *scope* operator. It's just an operator to denote scope, nothing else.

Comment: The double colon does not exist at runtime... it is only used by the compiler to choose the right method to call *at compile time*.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the double colon call to member is a thread-safe operation?

It is thread-safe if the function invoked is thread-safe.  For example:

```
class C
{
    static std::string mx;

public:
    static std::string fx(const char* x) { mx = x; return mx; } // NOT THREAD SAFE
    static std::string fy(const char* y) { return y; } // THREAD SAFE
};
```

You can call either function:

```
cout << C::fx("hello") << endl; // NOT THREAD SAFE
cout << C::fy("world") << endl; // THREAD SAFE
```

So it has nothing to do with the two colons, and everything to do with the method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

the `::` is nothing you even have to bother on runtime about. So yeah it is threadsafe as it is allready resolved when threads are comming into action.

The `::` is just used to make clear which namespace or class scope is refered to in cases where there could be ambiguous names.